# How to read back a fan speed?

Tags: embedded, yocto, device-tree, fan

I am on a custom board using an i.MX6.  I am using Yocto (Pyro) to build my kernel (4.14.16).

I am using the generic imx6qdl.dtsi device tree entry for PWM2 to drive the fan and it appears to work fine.  The fan has a Tachometer input, which is connected to GPIO2_7.  How do I read the fan speed?  I have seen device tree blobs for cooling devices, but none of the examples seem to have a tachometer to monitor the fan's speed.

Comment: Have you checked `/sys/class/hwmon/` (and `/sys/class/pwm/`)? I'm guessing yes, but just want to be sure there isn't an easy solution there.

Comment: I did.  I could set the PWM for the fan from the `/sys/class/pwm/` but there was no mechanism to read back the speed (just the PWM that i had set it to).  All that I have in `/sys/class/hwmon` were temperature sensors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to find a device tree solution, but found enough code snippets to make an application to read it.  Basically I just set up an interrupt on the GPIO and used `clock_gettime` to measure the period between edges.  It requires a lot of filtering, but I am only using it to make sure the fan is running so that is fine.

Comment: BTW, might be easier to count interrupts instead, and e.g., read your counter once per second (having your read thread sleep). Then you probably won't need filtering.